# Loop through arrays of objects and return sum by ID reference

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I'm taking an object that contains a group of objects, and I'm trying to loop through them to sum the data by id reference.

This is probably easier to show than to explain, if I have a function like this...

```
let projectArray = this.projects
    projectArray.forEach(function (el) {
        console.log(el.categoriesTotal)
    })
```

I get a nice return of arrays containing the objects I'm after, that looks like this.....

```
[
  { _id: 6, total: 4478.4 },
  { _id: 1, total: 110248.13 },
  { _id: 7, total: 663695.1 }
]
[
  { _id: 7, total: 31278 },
  { _id: 1, total: 67174.66 },
  { _id: 4, total: 3712.8 },
  { _id: 8, total: 670 }
]
...
```

What I want to do is return the sum totals by id reference, so for example

```
_id: 1, total: 177422.79,
_id: 6, total: 4478.4
```

I think that the method I want is 'reduce', but I tried following along with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22308576/6504075), and I got an error telling me that 'reduce is not a function', possibly because I was trying to 'reduce' more than one array.

How do I return the sum totals from these arrays?

Comment: So you have an array of arrays?

Comment: Did you try to generate a single array from your 2 dimension array and use reduce?

Comment: @Mulli I didn't try and generate a single array, no (not sure how)

Comment: Flat array, see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat

Comment: just use `flat()` method to your projectArray so it creates new array with all sub-array elements concatenated into it recursively up to the specified depth and then you can use reduce to sum up values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const data = [
  [
    { _id: 6, total: 4478.4 },
    { _id: 1, total: 110248.13 },
    { _id: 7, total: 663695.1 }
  ],
  [
    { _id: 7, total: 31278 },
    { _id: 1, total: 67174.66 },
    { _id: 4, total: 3712.8 },
    { _id: 8, total: 670 }
  ]
];

let temp = {};
data.forEach( arrayOfObjects => {
  arrayOfObjects.forEach( obj => {
    if(temp[obj._id] != null) {
      temp[obj._id] += obj.total
    }else{
      temp[obj._id] = obj.total
    }
  })
})
let result = [];
for ( [key,value] of Object.entries(temp) ){
  result.push({ _id: key*1, total: value })
}

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use [Array.flat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) to flatten the array, then use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to get the desired result, e.g.

```js
let a = [[
  { _id: 6, total: 4478.4 },
  { _id: 1, total: 110248.13 },
  { _id: 7, total: 663695.1 }
],
[
  { _id: 7, total: 31278 },
  { _id: 1, total: 67174.66 },
  { _id: 4, total: 3712.8 },
  { _id: 8, total: 670 }
]];

let result = Object.values(a.flat().reduce((map, r) => { 
    if (!map[r._id]) map[r._id] = { _id: r._id, total: 0};
    map[r._id].total += r.total;
    return map;
}, {}));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks, how do I get the arrays into an array? They're separate when I log them to the console from the forEach.

Comment: You can use the very handy array.flat() to flatten an array of arrays into one contiguous array.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array.prototype.flat` to flatten your array of arrays, and then just `reduce` to aggregate the sums.

```js
var projectArray = [[
  { _id: 6, total: 4478.4 },
  { _id: 1, total: 110248.13 },
  { _id: 7, total: 663695.1 }
],
[
  { _id: 7, total: 31278 },
  { _id: 1, total: 67174.66 },
  { _id: 4, total: 3712.8 },
  { _id: 8, total: 670 }
]];

var result = projectArray.flat().reduce( (acc,i) => {
   if(acc.hasOwnProperty(i._id))
       acc[i._id] += i.total;
   else
       acc[i._id] = i.total;
   return acc;
},{});
console.log(result);
```